# Create in-memory database using mongodb-memory-server and mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, in-memory-database

I want to create a in-memory database using mongodb-memory-server and mongoose. Can anyone show the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation [here](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server) and came accross the following solution.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server');

const mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer();

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoServer.getUri().then((mongoUri) => {
  const mongooseOpts = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  };

  mongoose.connect(mongoUri, mongooseOpts);

  mongoose.connection.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });

  mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log(`MongoDB successfully connected to ${mongoUri}`);
  });
});
module.exports=mongoose.connection;
```

Answer (score 3):

From version 7 and above

```
// this no longer works
const mongo = new MongoMemoryServer();
const uri = await mongo.getUri(); // ERROR: instance not started

// it is now
const mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
const uri = mongo.getUri();
```

https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/guides/migration/migrate7/#no-function-other-than-start-create-ensureinstance-will-be-starting-anything